# Шахматы на JS . Ошибка - Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, append

```
var cherssarr = [['','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', ''],

['8', '&#9820;', '&#9822;', '&#9821;', '&#9819;', '&#9812;', '&#9821;', '&#9822;','&#9820;','8'],

['7', '&#9823;', '&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;', '&#9823;','&#9823;', '&#9823;','7'],

['6', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '6'],
['5', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '5'],
['4', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '4'],
['3', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '3'],
['2', '&#9823;', '&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;', '&#9823;','2'],

['1', '&#9820;', '&#9822;', '&#9821;', '&#9819;', '&#9812;', '&#9821;', '&#9822;','&#9820;','1'],
[ '','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', '' ]];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    document.querySelector('#new-table').appendChild(tr);
    for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
    td.innerHTML = cherssarr[i][j];
    tr.appendChild ('td');
```

Answer (score 0):

Такой результат нужен?

```js
const cherssarr = [
  ['','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', ''],
  ['8', '&#9820;', '&#9822;', '&#9821;', '&#9819;', '&#9812;', '&#9821;', '&#9822;','&#9820;','8'],
  ['7', '&#9823;', '&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;', '&#9823;','&#9823;', '&#9823;','7'],
  ['6', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '6'],
  ['5', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '5'],
  ['4', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '4'],
  ['3', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '3'],
  ['2', '&#9823;', '&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;','&#9823;', '&#9823;','2'],
  ['1', '&#9820;', '&#9822;', '&#9821;', '&#9819;', '&#9812;', '&#9821;', '&#9822;','&#9820;','1'],
  [ '','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', '' ]
];

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    document.querySelector('#new-table').appendChild(tr);
    for(let j=0; j<10; j++){
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerHTML = cherssarr[i][j];
    }
 }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
td:last-child,
tr:first-child td {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<table id="new-table"></table>
```

Comment: почти  то что нужно. только нужно отзеркалить цифры и буквы  как на доске

Comment: @alyaalya, дополнил

Comment: Огромное спасибо!